# How to make a class inside a function using exec()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I'm creating a function that creates a class inside it and returns that...

```
    def create_object(**objects):
        # creates class, NewClass
        class NewClass:
            pass
        for key in objects.keys():
            # creating objects in NewClass
            exec("NewClass.%s = %s" % (key, objects[key]))
        return NewClass
```

and when we called this function,

```
new_object = create_object(first_name='Mayank', last_name='Tyagi')
new_object.first_name
```

this works fine and gives output

```
>>> 'Mayank'
```

but I want to create a function that will create a class with variable name.
eg

```
    def object(class_name, **objects):
        # create a class where the value of class_name is the name of class
        exec("class %s:\n\tpass" % (class_name))
        for key in objects.keys():
            # creating new objects in this class
            exec("NewClass.%s = %s" % (key, objects[key]))
```

and after calling the function,

```
object('ClassName', first_name='Mayank', last_name='Tyagi')
ClassName.first_name
```

it should give the output,

```
>>>'Mayank'
```

How to make this?

-asking for help with a hope:)

Comment: In the last line of 4th code block, it is: exec("%s.%s = %s" % (class_name,key,objects[key]))

Comment: The second `exec` should be `exec("%s.%s = %s" % (class_name, key, objects[key]))`. Although, I don't really encourage this type of design.

Comment: Don't use `exec`, use [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type): `cls = type(name, (object,), objects)`.

Answer (score 1):

dont use exec unless you absolutely have to, which you don't.

use `type`

```
def __init__(self, first, last):
    self.first = first
    self.last = last

cls_ = type("Mayank", (object,), dict(__init__=__init__))

obj = cls_("Mayank","Tyagi")

print(obj, vars(obj))
```

#### out:

```
<__main__.Mayank object at 0x1028050b8> {'first': 'Mayank', 'last': 'Tyagi'}
```

edit:  from Patrick's comment: whatever goes in that dictiory for the 3rd argument to `type` is a class-level attribute.  I assume the OP wants to create an instance of a class with a first and lastname instance-level attribute into which they want to want to store names, at the instance level.  Thus allowing different Mayank instances to have different names.  Of course, they could mean a class with a first and name, set at the class level of Mayank/Tyagi.  in which case those would be be passed into that dict directly, rather than providing an init function.

Subtlety:  even a class-level first and last name allows instance-level overrides:

```
m1 = Mayank()
m2 = Mayank()
m3 = Mayank()

m1.last = "Foo"
m2.last = "Bar"
```

printing last names for m1,m2,m3 would print Foo, Bar, Mayank respectively as the assignment happens at the instance level, without altering the class.

Comment: This answer is correct, but I think it could use an explanation of why you're passing the `__init__` function instead of the first and last names.